# Accessing Open Data Cube through Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, open-data-cube

I'm trying to access the product added to datacube through Jupyter Notebook. For this, I'm using this [demo notebook](https://github.com/opendatacube/datacube-notebooks/blob/master/Demo_Notebook.ipynb).

The command `import utils.data_cube_utilities.data_access_api as dc_api` showing error as

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-16-3b34ea0cb5ec> in <module>
----> 1 import utils.data_cube_utilities.data_access_api as dc_api
      2 api = dc_api.DataAccessApi(config = '/home/localuser/.datacube.conf')
      3 
      4 platform = "LANDSAT-8"
      5 name = "LC08_L2SP"

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'utils.data_cube_utilities'
```

I'm doing a local implementation of Open Data Cube. I've installed postgreSQL and indexed the data locally.

[image]

Comment: What environment are you running this? Your own custom datacube install, or an existing implementation, e.g. Digital Earth Australia or Digital Earth Africa?

Comment: @Robbi Bishop-Taylor  I have install the datacube. This is a local implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you download only that individual notebook and run it separately? If so, I suspect this is because you need to instead clone the entire repository located here: https://github.com/opendatacube/datacube-notebooks

```
git clone https://github.com/opendatacube/datacube-notebooks.git
```

Once you have that repo cloned locally, you should be able to run the `Demo_Notebook.ipynb` notebook from its existing location and all the Python module imports should work correctly. If you still run into problems, try adding the `utils` directory containing the Python modules you need to the system path:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('<path_to_utils_directory>')
utils.data_cube_utilities.data_access_api as dc_api
```

Please note however that some of those notebooks are several years old, and may not work as originally intended. There's a list of more up to date Open Data Cube notebook resources here: https://opendatacube.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/notebooks.html

Comment: Thank You, I followed these steps. This method should work but didn't work in my case. So after cloning the repository, as the error was in importing **_data_access_api_** which is a python file present under **_datacube-notebooks\utils\data_cube_utilities_**, I copied the content of that python file directly to the jupyter notebook. **_data_access_api.py_** contains the definition a class named **_DataAccessApi_**. I created an instance of that class and that worked. This may be not the correct way but as I'm doing just a local installation for learning it's OK for me.